# CXF AddressingPropertiesImpl cannot be cast to JBoss AddressingPropertiesImpl

Tags: cxf, jax-ws, classcastexception, wildfly, jbossws

I am using SLSB as a webservice with `@Addressing` annotation and `@HandlerChain` of type `org.jboss.wsf.common.handler.GenericSOAPHandler` (jbossws-common)

My client uses WSAddressingClientHandler to BindingProvider

Like:

```
customHandlerChain.add(new WSAddressingClientHandler());
bindingProvider.getBinding().setHandlerChain(customHandlerChain);
```

I override `handleOutbound(MessageContext msgContext)` at client side and the soap message with header and body is sent successfully to the webservice

at server side in `handleInbound(MessageContext msgContext)` I try to read `msgContext` with

like:

```
org.jboss.ws.extensions.addressing.AddressingPropertiesImpl addrProps = org.jboss.ws.extensions.addressing.AddressingPropertiesImpl)msgContext.get(   JAXWSAConstants.SERVER_ADDRESSING_PROPERTIES_INBOUND);
```

At this line i get `ClassCastException` from cxf library.
This service is hosted on WildFly 8.1.0 Final. 
Any ideas how to get ahead of this exception.

```
WARNING [org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain] (default task-42) Interceptor for {http://jee.v1.profspec.profile.lucent.alcatel/}pfmjainslee11#{http://jee.v1.profspec.profile.lucent.alcatel/}create has thrown exception, unwinding now: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.cxf.ws.addressing.impl.AddressingPropertiesImpl cannot be cast to org.jboss.ws.extensions.addressing.AddressingPropertiesImpl
        at alu.osp.smf.JBossSessionHandler.handleInbound(JBossSessionHandler.java:98) [smf.jar:20140827.42668]
        at org.jboss.wsf.common.handler.GenericHandler.handleMessage(GenericHandler.java:53) [jbossws-common.jar:1.1.0.GA]
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.handler.HandlerChainInvoker.invokeHandleMessage(HandlerChainInvoker.java:359)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.handler.HandlerChainInvoker.invokeHandlerChain(HandlerChainInvoker.java:255)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.handler.HandlerChainInvoker.invokeProtocolHandlers(HandlerChainInvoker.java:132)
        at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.interceptor.HandlerAuthInterceptor$JBossWSHandlerChainInvoker.invokeProtocolHandlers(HandlerAuthInterceptor.java:112)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.handler.soap.SOAPHandlerInterceptor.handleMessageInternal(SOAPHandlerInterceptor.java:169)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.handler.soap.SOAPHandlerInterceptor.handleMessage(SOAPHandlerInterceptor.java:124)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.handler.soap.SOAPHandlerInterceptor.handleMessage(SOAPHandlerInterceptor.java:71)
        at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272) [cxf-api-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121) [cxf-api-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:241)
        at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.RequestHandlerImpl.handleHttpRequest(RequestHandlerImpl.java:93)
        at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.transport.ServletHelper.callRequestHandler(ServletHelper.java:133)
        at 
org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.CXFServletExt.invoke(CXFServletExt.java:88)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:286)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:206)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707) [jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
        at 
org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.CXFServletExt.service(CXFServletExt.java:136)
        at 
org.jboss.wsf.spi.deployment.WSFServlet.service(WSFServlet.java:140) [jbossws-spi-2.2.2.Final.jar:2.2.2.Final]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) [jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:61)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:113)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:56)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:45)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:61)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:240)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:227)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:73)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:146)
        at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:177)
        at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:727)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
```

Comment: I am facing the same issue. This is probably because Jboss already has this class. I have `cxf-api` and `cxf-rt-ws-addr` dependencies in my application. When I remove these dependencies, I get NoClassDefFoundError for `AddressingPropertiesImpl`. Probably, jboss cxf module is not loaded on time.